# How to recover a file after rm() in rstudio project?

Tags: r, rstudio

I `rm(mydataframe)` from my project in rstudio.(that's a mistake by long time work)
I clike `edit`- `undo`, but nothing happen.
Then, How to recover `mydataframe`?  I believe rstudio has this feature.

Comment: You may have how you originally created the dataframe in the "History" tab. You can save the history to file as well if you like. Else, build a time machine?

Answer (score 1):

You may have how you originally created the dataframe in the "History" tab. You can save the history to file as well if you like. Else, build a time machine?